# If statement Could not parse the remainder: '|' from '|"

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to use a filter inside of an if statement and whenever I do, I get the error below.

I have looked through for typos and wasn't able to catch anything.

Details.html (the template)

```py
{% extends "dashboard/header.html" %}

{% block content %}

{% load custom_filts %}

<h1>{{ result }} <span class="badge badge-pill badge-info" style="background-color: {{ colour | hexify }}">{{ result | get_model_name }}</span></h1>

{% if result|get_model_name == "Fixture" %}
    {% block fixture_data %}
    {% endblock %}
{% elif result | get_model_name == "Cable" %}
    {% block cable_data %}
    {% endblock %}
{% elif result | get_model_name == "Adapter" %}
    {% block adapter_data %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

My custom filters

```py
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def get_model_name(value):
    return value.__class__.__name__

@register.filter
def hexify(value):
    return "#" + value
```

When this is used, I get this error:

```py
TemplateSyntaxError at /dashboard/detail/1
Could not parse the remainder: '|' from '|'
```

Comment: the space after `|`  `result | get_model_name` is the problem, use `result|get_model_name`

Comment: You should remove the spaces before and after the `|`.